# Deleting objects using checkboxes with Codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, checkbox

I have read many post like this but have failed to find my particular situation.Trying to delete the selected checkbox. right now you can submit the form and it takes you to all the right pages except it doesn't actually delete anything.

Here is my controller info

```
function deleteFolder() {
   if(array_key_exists('deleteMe',$_POST)) {
      $checkbox = $this->input->post['checkbox']; 
      $this->index_model->deleteFolder($checkbox);
   }
 $this->folderdeleted();
}
```

Here is my Model

```
function deleteFolder($checkbox) {
  $this->db->where('folderName', 'folderName'); 
  $this->db->delete('senior', $checkbox);
return;
}
```

Here is my View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php $this->load->view('partials/page_head'); ?> 
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="top">
      <div class="topcenter">
       <h2><a class="homebtn" href="<?php echo base_url();?>">Home</a></h2>
      </div>
      <div class="navdescription"><span>Delete Page</span></div>
    </div>
      <div class="projectFolders">
      <?php foreach($foldername as $row) { ?>
        <div class="folder">
          <button><?php echo $row->folderName; ?></button>
          <div class="delete">
            <form name="delete" method="post" action="<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/home/folderdeleted">    
              <p>
                <input type = "checkbox" id = "check_<?php echo $row->folderName; ?>"/>
                <?php echo form_submit('deleteFolder', 'Delete'); ?>
              </p>
          </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
  </div><!-- End of container div -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your error and [] these beackets are not used () are used in $this->input->post()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several errors in your code. I'm not sure whether I've found all of them and whether the code will work.

The controller should be:

```
function deleteFolder() {
   if($this->input->post('checkbox') !== false) {
      $checkbox = $this->input->post('checkbox');
      $this->index_model->deleteFolder($checkbox);
   }
 $this->folderdeleted();
}
```

The model should be:

```
function deleteFolder($checkbox) {
  $this->db->where('folderName', $checkbox); 
  $this->db->delete('senior');
return;
}
```

The input tag in the view should be:

```
                <input name="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row->folderName; ?>" type = "checkbox" id = "check_<?php echo $row->folderName; ?>"/>
```

A little warning for checkboxes: if they aren't checked, you won't find anything in the $_POST variable.

Comment: So i am still having problems even with those fixes(thanks). Here is a link to my project on Github if you need a better understanding of what i am doing wrong haha.                                  https://github.com/travi5567/SeniorProject.git

Comment: I do not get any errors, the object doesnt actually delete is the problem. Wish i had an error to help me out

Comment: Maybe you can try to print out some variables to locate the problem. For instance `var_dump($_POST)` in the controller function or `var_dump($this->db->queries)` in the model after the delete statement. The last one will print out the last queries that were sent to the database and you could manually check the last query in the database (e.g. try the query out in phpmyadmin and see what the result is).